# Can't find C/C++ IntelliJ IDEA Plugin

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to add a [c/c++ plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1373?pr=idea&showAllUpdates=true) to IntelliJ IDEA, so I went to plugins and searched for it but couldn't find it.
Did they remove it and replace it with their new IDE cLion? Is it no longer supported or what?

[image]

Comment: I can confirm that it really isn't in the list of available plugins, if that helps. It does look like it has been removed. Perhaps Jetbrains didn't want the competition for CLion.

Comment: @EngineerDollery, indeed! JetBrains recommend the CLion so it would be pointless for them to keep a plugin for IntelliJ and CLion on the other hand.

Comment: @SimplyMe: it's not pointless for them. they had IDE's for ruby and python and still support their IntelliJ IDEA Plugins.

Comment: @humazed, yes, but in my opinion, the CLion is better because you have an IDEE dedicated for C/C++, and this way, you can "personalize" it better.

Comment: @SimplyMe I don't like having to maintain multiple IDEs if I shouldn't have to. I don't limit my work strictly to C/C++ so a plugin for IDEA would be more suitable for me. they already boast IDEA does the same thing as their individual lightweight IDEs, so I don't see why I should have to download a lightweight IDE when I could just add a plugin that does the same thing to a heavyweight IDE.

Comment: @Tcll That plugin isn't official. It's developed by some third party called AdvancedTools. I guess they simply stopped updating the plugin (not sure if it's related to the release of CLion or not). Currently the only way to get official C/C++ support within the IntelliJ ecosystem is to buy JetBrains CLion. See my answer below. JetBrains might plan to release a standalone plugin in the future but that's not their priority for now.

Comment: @JIXiang: I wasn't complaining, I was making a statement about the hassles of multiple IDEs. Thanks though, I didn't pay attention to the details of the plugin vs CLion, and wasn't intending on implying much of a connection between them if they did or not, but yeah, unfortunately that is how it is... -_-

Comment: If only basic syntax highlighting is ok for cpp files, you can add `*.cpp` into `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `File Types`, and look for `C/C++` (by default only *.c, and *.cc are listed).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Looks like the version of your IntelliJ IDEA is newer than what the C/C++ plugin supports. If you look at the [plugin page](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1373?pr=) you can see that builds from 139.1 until 142 are compatible. And if you look [here](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/build_number_ranges.html) you can see that build 141 is IntelliJ 14.1 and IntelliJ IDEA 15 is numbered 143. So my guess is you are using IntelliJ IDEA 15 or 16 EAP and therefore the plugin is not shown when you search for it.

Comment: so .. no support for `C++` in recent versions of IJ ?

Comment: There is much much better support for C/C++ in the [CLion IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/).

Comment: Saw that - I'd just prefer to keep inside one env instead of IJ/pycharm/Clion ..   I'll just use the syntax highlighting for now.

Comment: @javadba That plugin isn't official. It's developed by some third party called AdvancedTools. Currently the only way to get official C/C++ support within the IntelliJ ecosystem is to buy JetBrains CLion. See my answer below. JetBrains might plan to release a standalone plugin in the future but that's not their priority for now.

Answer (score 22):

Simply download the cpp plugin of the old 14 version located here:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1373-c-c-

Then edit the file CppTools/META-INF/plugin.xml and replace the "until-build" value in line 5 to something like  until-build="170.0"

And this works perfectly :)

Comment: You can simply remove the until-build property. Still works in 2017.1

Comment: **Don't do this anymore**, it will make your IntellijIDEA crash at startup. If this happens, just delete the plugin from the folder it has been installed

Answer (score 18):

One should really note that the "C/C++" plugin available in the IntelliJ Plugin Repository is actually not developed by Jetbrains, but by a third party called `AdvancedTools`, and has long not been updated. I'm not sure if that is related to the release of CLion, e.g. IntelliJ bought out the plugin to serve as the foundation of CLion or whatnot.

As listed in the [CLion FAQ page](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2014/09/clion-answers-frequently-asked-questions/), there is currently **no official standalone plugin** for C/C++ editing available for IntelliJ IDEA. Just as with some other products such as Jetbrains AppCode, Jetbrains are currently keeping CLion as an exclusively paid product, **without a free community edition**, as indicated in [this forum post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206558629-Is-there-a-community-edition-for-CLion-Is-CLion-available-as-a-plugin-for-IntelliJ-IDEA-).

The post also confirmed that a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA might be coming in the future, but is currently (Jan 2018) not a priority for JetBrains.

So yeah for now the only way to get decent C/C++ support within the IntelliJ ecosystem is to use/buy JetBrains CLion.

Answer (score 8):

Download latest version of c/c++ extension from link: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1373-c-c-

then open that CppTools.zip inside META-INF folder open file plugin.xml modify line five  until-build="" from your own intellij idea build. Go to Help --> About in Your Intellij idea.

[image: Go to Help --> About]

plugin.xml file screenshot:

[image: Plugin.xml]

Now Go to File --> Settings --> Plugins --> Install plugins from Disk, browse ypur edited/ modified CppTools.zip.

Comment: as a word of caution: if you do that with the 2022 release you break it.
Still trying to find how to remove the plugin manually

Answer (score -1):

I faced this problem before and i figure out that the software i install it was old and not update, so try to see the plugin version and see is that plugin version compatible with your intellij-idea, if not check update for the intelli-idea ,the developers fix many problems in every update ,then download it.
 you can check compatibility from this page.
[Here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1373-c-c-)

Answer (score -2):

Click on `Preferences -> Plugins -> Browse Repositories` and search for it

[image: Browse repositories]

Comment: just looking at the image isn't this exactly what the OP has tried already?

Comment: And, manage repositories doesn't allow you to search for anything.

Comment: what IDE do use, is it IntelliJ IDEA or what!

Comment: I use PHPStorm,

wikipedia : JetBrains PhpStorm is a commercial, cross-platform IDE for PHP built on JetBrains' IntelliJ IDEA platform.

Comment: @akabhirav That plugin isn't official. It's developed by some third party called `AdvancedTools`. Currently the only way to get official C/C++ support within the IntelliJ ecosystem is to buy JetBrains CLion. See my answer below. JetBrains might plan to release a standalone plugin in the future but that's not their priority for now.