# I'm using Goland, but now is coming a project having both Go and C++ files inside. Am I forced to move to VS Code?

Tags: c++, go, visual-studio-code, goland

Until now, my projects were plain Go ones, and I managed them with *Goland*.

But now, a new one is coming having both `Go` and `C++` files.
(some `Go` functions are implemented with the help of `C++` methods and `CGO`)

The *Goland* editor can show me `Go` sources, allows me to edit it, show me errors on them... like the Go IDE it is,
...but when it is in front of a `C++` source, it can't do nothing.

This is why, my teammates are telling me that I can't escape moving to *VS Code*
who handles the two langages in the same project, by the mean of two plugins (one `Go`, one `C++`).
But I'm reluctant to, because I'm used with Jetbrains IDE.

I know the question look a dumb one, but I have to ask it:
Do I have a way to handle C++ sources files in *Goland*?

Comment: Have you checked the list of JetBrains plugins? I think there's a Go plugin for the C and C++ IDE Clion, so there might be a C/C++ plugin for Goland?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I can see (at home) that CLion has Jetbrains official Go templates plugins, but at work, where there's only Goland available, I don't see C++ plugins for it. None allowing to edit C++ files, at least compile them with `g++` and do some syntax checking... for what I see. Maybe it's impossible. This is why I am asking on Stack Overflow for a last chance. If my projects start having both `Go` and `C` or `C++` and Goland is not adapted, I might have no choice. For inspections, Goland is stronger than VS Code, I will feel a quality loss going from Golang to VS Code.

Comment: I can't see a C/C++ plugin for GoLand either, which means you need Clion if you want to stay within the JetBrains sphere. If you need this as part of your work-assignment, you should talk to your boss. If your work isn't providing the tools you need then you can't do the assignments and tasks they give you. If you need to work with C++, then you need an IDE capable of that, which means CLion.

Comment: Goland is dedicated to `Go`. A good `C`, `C++` plugin could give to it nice abilities in `C`, `C++`. But CLion is dedicated to `C`, `C++`, and the `Go` plugin might give to it average or good abilities with `Go` langage, but no dedicate it as much as Goland is. Whatever, what's required today isn't here, and the quickest move that come on everyone mind (except me) is to abandon Goland and go to VS Code, because VS Code handles both languages. It's sad, like @TehSphinX checked it, that the `C`, `C++` plugin that exists works on everything _except_ Goland but Jetbrains has surely an explanation

Comment: `C, C++ plugin that exists works on everything except Goland` -- It does work with Goland. I guess just not with the latest version(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [C/C++ plugin for JetBrains](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1373-c-c-) products. It also supports Goland, but the version of Goland you are using might not be supported, yet.

The same has been asked in [Can't find C/C++ IntelliJ IDEA Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34899937/cant-find-c-c-intellij-idea-plugin).

Goland is mentioned as being supported, but my current version is not supported:

[image]

Comment: [The wish for that feature is submitted](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-16376/Go-functions-can-be-implemented-with-the-help-of-C-C-methods-but-Goland-cannot-edit-and-compile-C-and-C-source-files.-No-C-C).